# Why can't my EJB ReST service extend an abstract class from a seperate jar?

Tags: java, rest, ejb, weblogic12c

So, I have a stateless EJB in a .war file.

This EJB is used as a ReST service.

In an jar, I have an abstract class with some methods implemented.

The service EJB extends the abstract class from the jar.

When I try to deploy this .war file to WebLogic 12c, I get the following error:

> AppMerge failed to merge your application.

I am unsure as to why this error occurs.

This is what my abstract class looks like in the jar:

```
public abstract class AbstractService
{
  public Response runService(final ServiceParams parameter)
  {
    return Response.ok().build();
  }
}
```

This is what the service implementation looks like in the war:

```
@Path("/")
@Stateless
public class MyService extends AbstractService
{
  @GET
  @Path("/run")
  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  @Override
  public Response runService(final @QueryParam("jsonParamObjectId") ServiceParams parameter)
  {
    return super.runService(parameter);
  }
}
```

This configuration and code deploys successfully in Glassfish 3.1.2.2.

Any ideas as to why WebLogic 12c is giving me issues?

I'm sure this is a classloading issue whose solution I keep missing.

Thanks in advance for any insights!

Comment: Is there some kind of exception stack trace? check the server logs. its impossible to deduce your problem by just that Generic error message.

Comment: I have been unable to figure out how to dig into the exception details, as the exception only occurs through some proprietary WebLogic classes.
I will try to find out more information on how to enable more detailed logging, but I'm not sure how much control I have over that part of the deployment.

Comment: This error generally happens when weblogic doesn't like the directory structure of your EAR file. Check the diagram here: http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/EAR_Application_Diagram.jpg and more notes here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13218_01/wlp/docs81/prodOps/deployment.html